# Unable to record video using screenrecord in android programatically

Tags: android

I trying to record the video using screenrecord utility in android lollipop using the following code.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screenrecord /sdcard/test.mp4",null,null);
Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
p.destroy();
```

It creates the file in sdcard but nothing is recorded and file size is zero.

If I use the below command in adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/test.mp4. It is working fine.

Is anybody come across this scenario.

Note : I am using the below permission in the app.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Device is Non-Rooted device

Answer (score 0):

> Device is Non-Rooted device

Then you cannot run `screenrecord`. That is a development-time tool that is not usable by ordinary SDK apps.